# How to do model bulk interpolate in Django REST Framework 3?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have User model, Friend spanning model between a pair of Users. Trying to serialize list of particular users to achieve something like:

```
[{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Foo"
 "is_friend": true
},
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Bar"
"is_friend": false
}]
```

I use ModelSerializer everywhere I can through the app so the first solution that came to my mind is to just implement `is_friend` computed property on User model and just create read only property in the serializer, but just imagine the underneath SQL hell. For every user there's going to be another SQL select which doesn't seem like good enough solution for me at all. So I thought about something like getting my friends, getting my particular users I want the relation to be compare with and do the job on Python side using just 2 SQL selects. I'm wondering what would be the most elegant solution doing that in DRF3? Are there any patters for doing such things? Any ideas? Would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to load needed data at once. Or `extra` can do the job as well.

Comment: As an alternative you could go for a DB view and a corresponding model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to nest your serializers to achieve this. For example:

```
class RelatedFriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FriendModle
        fields = ('id', '...')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    relatedfriendserializer = RelatedFriendSerializer(read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'relatedfriendserializer',)
```

In your model definition, the related name between `User` and `Friend` should be called `relatedfriendserializer`